# read a character from a string via inline assembler in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86

I'm having a problem with the visual studio inline assembler and it doesn't seem to be loading the right values. I declare a C-string like so:

```
const char* str = "1235";
```

Then I access the string like so in asm:

```
movzx ebx, byte ptr str[esi]
```

the problem is that instead of loading 49 into ebx (ascii code for '1') it loads 0. I'm sure that esi is the right index because of extensive debugging. am I loading the string wrong?

Comment: What value is in esi when you do the `mov ebx, str[esi]`?

Comment: @JerryCoffin esi is being used as a counter in a loop, in this case it's 0

Comment: @PgrAm - If you use a register in your asm code, doesn't that change the code for the surrounding loop? I bet it does!

Comment: @BoPersson It's not a loop in the C sense of the word. its just a conditional jump expression at the end of an asm block. changing said registers have no effect

Comment: You are not indexing the string pointer. You are indexing the variable. The x86 does not have a double-indirection addressing mode. Look at the assembly generated by the compiler to see what is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instruction

```
movzx ebx, byte ptr str[esi]
```

says to read the byte that is `esi` bytes after the start of `str`. It is the assembly language equivalent of

```
ebx = *(unsigned char*)(&str) + esi);
```

In your case, `str` is a pointer variable, so `str[0]` is the low 8 bits of the pointer, `str[1]` is bits 8-15, `str[2]` is bits 16-23, and `str[3]` is bits 24-31. Any value larger than 3 is a buffer overflow because you are reading memory that is not part of `str`.

What you actually want to do to load the `str` variable into a register, and then do indexed addressing from that register.

```
mov ebx, str
movzx ebx, byte ptr [ebx+esi]
```

In pictures:

```
         +----+
    1003 | 12 |
         +----+
    1002 | 34 |
         +----+
    1001 | 56 |
         +----+
str 1000 | 78 |
         +----+

             +----+
    1234567D | 00 |
             +----+
    1234567C | 45 |
             +----+
    1234567B | 44 |
             +----+
    1234567A | 43 |
             +----+
    12345679 | 42 |
             +----+
    12345678 | 41 |
             +----+
```

You are trying to read byte `str+esi`, which reads part of the variable `str`. If `esi` is greater than 3, you are reading past the end of `str`.

What you actually want to do is read the thing that `str` points to. This means that you need to load `str` into a register (I chose `ebx`), then add `esi` to the result, then access the byte there.

Comment: yeah I did that and it worked! I did this "mov edi, str" and then this "movzx ebx, byte ptr [edi + esi]"

Comment: I hope you understand what is going on rather than just copying the answer blindly.

Comment: well I actually solved this problem on my own last night. Since you gave me the right answer I figured I should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
movzx     ebx, byte ptr str[esi]
```

Comment: The problem is that `str` is not an array so you cannot access its contents with this addressing mode.